# Incompatible datatypes in subtract operator in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

Trying to get `average_cost_2017` and `average_cost_2016` difference in dollars but getting this error:

> The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator.

I don't know how to subtract these two columns. I am using SQL Server 2008.

Here is the code I am using

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    od.productcode as Product_SKU,
    o1.Quantity AS 'JULY 2017 Quantity',
    o1.Average_Price AS  'JULY 2017 Average_price',
    o1.Average_Cost AS  'JULY 2017 Average_cost',
    o2.Quantity AS 'JULY 2016 Quantity',
    o2.Average_Price AS  'JULY 2016 Average_price',
    o2.Average_Cost AS  'JULY 2016 Average_cost',
    '$' + CAST((o1.Average_Cost-o2.Average_Cost ) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS DIFF_COST
FROM
    OrderDetails od
JOIN 
    Orders o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID 
JOIN
    (SELECT 
         productcode,
         SUM(od.Quantity) as Quantity,
         '$' + CAST((SUM((od.ProductPrice) * (od.Quantity)) / SUM(od.Quantity))AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Average_Price,
         '$' + CAST(( SUM(od.Vendor_Price) / COUNT(od.Quantity))AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Average_Cost
     FROM
         OrderDetails od
     JOIN
         Orders o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID 
     JOIN 
         Customers c ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
     WHERE
         o.OrderStatus <> 'Cancelled'
         AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN '07/01/17 00:00' AND '07/31/17 23:59'
         AND od.ProductPrice <> 0
         AND od.Quantity NOT LIKE 0
         AND c.CustomerID NOT IN ('10042', '429173') 
     GROUP BY
         productcode) AS o1 ON o1.ProductCode = od.ProductCode
JOIN
    (SELECT 
         productcode,
         SUM(od.Quantity) as Quantity,
         '$' + CAST((SUM((od.ProductPrice) * (od.Quantity)) / SUM(od.Quantity))AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Average_Price,
         '$' + CAST(( SUM(od.Vendor_Price) / COUNT(od.Quantity))AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Average_Cost
     FROM
         OrderDetails od
     JOIN
         Orders o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID 
     JOIN 
         Customers c ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
     WHERE 
         o.OrderStatus <> 'Cancelled'
         AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN '07/01/16 00:00' AND '07/31/16 23:59'
         AND od.ProductPrice <> 0
         AND od.Quantity NOT LIKE 0
         AND c.CustomerID NOT IN ('10042', '429173') 
     GROUP BY
         productcode) AS o2 ON o2.ProductCode = od.ProductCode
```

Comment: MySQL is not **My**crosoft SQL.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel sorry about that..I am using MS SQL 2008.

Comment: just remove all of the $ stuff and handle this in the application layer... it is at least pointless in your subqueries.

Comment: @scsimon after removing $ sign also it is not working and giving me error  Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'. I changed it to  (CAST(o1.Average_Cost) as int)-CAST(o2.Average_Cost) as int)) as DIFF_COST and got this new error

Comment: i assumed you were only casting because you were trying to add a numeric value to a dollar sign. There is no point to cast in this case, if you remove the $ sign.

Comment: @scsimon. Then how to do difference of o1.Average_cost and o2.Average_cost??? As if i dont use cast it gives me error saying The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator

Comment: You need to change sections like this `'$' + CAST(( SUM(od.Vendor_Price) / COUNT(od.Quantity))AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Average_Cost` to something like `SUM(od.Vendor_Price) / COUNT(od.Quantity) AS Average_Cost`

Comment: @scsimon but i want currency to be printed too. Is there a way to do both?

Comment: Yes, handle that in the application layer or only do your cast in the outer query, not the sun-queries

Comment: Sub-queries* not sun-queries

Comment: @scsimon not able to get dollar sign with diff cost even after moving cast to outer queries  ;(

Comment: Leave the cast in the outer and remove it from the inner. The problem is you are trying to do math on a varchar

Comment: @scsimon..yeah it is working but only concern is not printing $ sign with diff_cost.I want that too